# AngularJS Server Backend Handle Incoming HTTP Requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I just started learning AngularJS for my website development, and its perfect for what I need. However, I'm very new to web programming and I've been looking for the answer to my question for a while now, and I couldn't get a clear response. I'm wondering how I can handle incoming HTTP Requests in my AngularJS application.

For example, I'm going to have a computer running a program that is going to be constantly sending HTTP Post requests with data to the web server running my Angular app. I want to be able to parse the information in the app, and display the data using Angular's data binding. But, I can't figure out how in Angular you can listen for incoming HTTP requests, parse the data, and send back a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is designed for front-end web apps. You use to make an HTTP request from the users web browser to a webserver listening for such calls. But angular itself can't listen for them.

If you want to be able to listen for a HTTP request you will want to try either apache/php or nodejs/express. nodejs will probably work best for you because you can program in javascript.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about nodejs. I'll check it out.